# LARAVEL Why model events not fired for superclass Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In ServiceProvider I have :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
....
public function registerEvents()
{
    Model::saved(function ($model) {
        exit('saved');
    });
}
```

And when I save User this is not working, but with :

```
use App\Models\BaseModel\User;
....
public function registerEvents()
{
    User::saved(function ($model) {
        exit('saved');
    });
}
```

works fine ... why ?